# how to make svg animation scaling around a center of a figure?

Tags: animation, svg, scale

I'm trying to pulsate a star by using `animateTransform` with `type="scale"`, but instead of scaling around a center of the star, it scales to left and down. How to scale the star around the center?

Svg code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="star" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="170px" y="385px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 60 60" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <polygon fill="#DAC978" points="18.832,36.694 5.903,25.156 23.146,23.419 30.125,7.557 37.104,23.419 54.347,25.155 41.417,36.694 45.095,53.629 30.125,44.898 15.155,53.63" />
        <path fill="#A58144" d="M30.125,13.765l4.104,9.327l1.175,2.669l2.901,0.292l10.139,1.021l-7.603,6.785L38.665,35.8l0.618,2.851 l2.162,9.957l-8.801-5.134l-2.519-1.469l-2.52,1.469l-8.803,5.134l2.162-9.957l0.619-2.85l-2.175-1.942l-7.603-6.785l10.139-1.021 l2.901-0.292l1.174-2.669L30.125,13.765 M30.125,1.35l-8.681,19.729L0,23.237l16.08,14.352l-4.574,21.063l18.62-10.858 l18.618,10.858L44.17,37.589l16.081-14.352l-21.445-2.159L30.125,1.35L30.125,1.35z" />
        <animateTransform 
            attributeType="xml"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="scale"
            from="0"
            by="1"
            dur="1s" 
            repeatCount="10"
        />

    </g>
</svg>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayD2N/43/) with working code.

Comment: here is the working code http://jsfiddle.net/ayD2N/43/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`animateTransform` type `scale` seems to scale always from origin at `(0, 0)`. One possible solution can be in translating your polygon so that its center is in `(0, 0)`.

Here is working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ayD2N/45/).

Changes made to your original code:

- The viewbox is changed from `viewBox="0 0 60 60"` to `viewBox="-30 -30 60 60"` in order to have center of the `viewBox` at `(0, 0)` (for more on `viewBoxes` you can see [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html#viewbox))
- `polygon` and `path` are grouped and then translated so that their center is at `(0, 0)` too:

  ```
  <g transform="translate(-30,-30)">
      <polygon ... />
      <path ... />
  </g>
  ```